# Include Facebook's FB.api to jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Is it possible to include Facebook's *function postLike* into jquery code below to work on **button click or submit**?

```
function postLike(){FB.api("/me/og.likes","post",{object:"http://test.com/test"})}

$(".bookmark_form").live("submit",function(a){a.preventDefault();$.post("/",
$(this).serialize(),function(){$("#buddy").html("&nbsp;");
$.ajax({url:$("#buddy").attr("rel"),
dataType:"html",success:function(c){$("#buddy").html(c)}});return false})});
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Yes. It is possible. And it is done all the time.

Comment: Tommy, would you be so kind to show how to do this with my example... I guess I'm too stupid & miss smth. but I can't get it working. That will be so awesome help for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is highly possible.

Include the JS SDK. Include jQuery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#id of button").click(function(){
   FB.api('/me/og.likes',{object:'URL OF YOUR OPEN GRAPH OBJECT'}, function(response){
    if(response){
       alert(Success! It was liked!");
    }else{
       alert("Failure! Something went wrong.");
    }
  });
});

});
```

On that *URL OF YOUR OPEN GRAPH OBJECT*, you must implement an object via the [Open Graph Protocol](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/)